# Jquery Hide not working in second page of Datatables

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, bootstrap-4

I have a JQuery function that hides the Datatables when clicking a button on the table and then shows a form. It works on the first page but on the other pages it does not work and when I use the search query to search for a user and I click on the button (after query) the hide Jquery command does not work

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#past_years').DataTable({
            select: true
        });
        $('#insert_form').hide();


        $("#add_button").click(function () {
            $('#wrapper').hide();
            $('#insert_form').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of your code & page HTML structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#past_years').DataTable({
                select: true
            });
            $('#insert_form').hide();


            $(document).on("click","#add_button",function () {
                $('#wrapper').hide();
                $('#insert_form').show();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: the reason is you add add_button after dom creation that's why your code is not working

Comment: Yeah as satish mentioned its not working as you have bound the click event to whats on the page on load, then you come along and add some more elements with page two and they do not have your function bound to them. The above method works fine and is good. You could also use data table events to re-add your click binding to the specific elements each time the table is drawn https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw